# Java RegEx - for an Integer not containing a "."

Tags: java, regex, integer

I need to be able to return signed and unsigned integer constants with no
intervening symbols, possibly preceded by + or -. The only allowed digits are 3, 4, and 5.

I can't figure out a way to say that the expression must not contain a period before or after the integer.

This is what I have so far, but if I pass say "34.5 - 43" the string returned will be:    "34 5 43".

All that needs to be returned is "43".

```
public String getInts(String toBeScanned){

    String INT = "";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[+-]?[3-5]+\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(toBeScanned);

    if (m.matches() == true){
        INT = toBeScanned;
    }
    else{
        m = p.matcher(" " + toBeScanned);
        while (m.find()){
        INT = INT + m.group() + " ";
        }
    }
    return INT;
}
```

Any thoughts or pushes in the right direction are appreciated. Is there a way to say it that the first and last character can be [\b and not .]

This is frustrating the heck out of me. Help!

Comment: "\\b?(?:([+-]?[3-5.]+) ?)+\\b?" and get the last group of the matcher?

Comment: Acdtually, `\b` is broken in Java patterns as a word boundary ***unless*** you **either** use 7-bit characters only not Java’s native charset, **or else** you use [the Java 7 Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) compilation optional or equivalent embedded `"(?U)"` flag. So either make sure you have 7-bit data, or else use the new flag, or else don’t use `\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a word boundary `\b` here. I think the best is to create your own assertion, try this

```
(?<![.\d])[+-]?[3-5]+(?![.\d])
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?304m9)

`(?<![.\d])` is a negative lookbehind assertion, it says before the pattern is no dot and no digit allowed.

`(?![.\d])` is a negative lookahead assertion, it says after the  pattern is no dot and no digit allowed.

**Improvement**

to avoid that it matches stuff like "hf34" we can make it more strict

```
(?<![.\w])[+-]?[3-5]+(?![.\w])
```

See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?304mc)

**The word boundary `\b`**

`\b` matches on a change from a word character to a non word character. A word character is a letter or a digit or a `_`. That means you will also get problems with your `\b` before the `[+-]`, because there is no `\b` between a space/start of the string and a `[+-]`.

Comment: The problem is by saying (?<![.\d]) there is no dot and no digit allowed, but anything else is, so if " hf35 43" was passed, the string returned would be "35 43", when it should only return "43".

Comment: then just change the `\d` to `\w`. `(?<![.\w])[+-]?[3-5]+(?![.\w])`.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. This works beautifully. And Regexr is a nice tool, thanks for showing me. I would have never figured that out, so thanks a ton.

Comment: Remember that your definition of `\b` is ***only true of 7-bit data***, and that it will misbehave on Unicode if you don’t use [the new flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) from Java 7. Before then Java Patterns were not usable with `\b` on the native charset.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for the info. I knew that there has been a lot improvements for regex in Java 7, but till now I was unaware of this flag.

Answer (score 0):

"\b[+-]?[3-5]+[.][3-5]+\b"

This pattern says that in order to match, there must be at least one number before, and one number after the decimal point.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. If there is a "." preceding or following the number it needs to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to say it that the first and last character can be [\b and not .]

```
[^\.\b]
```

matches \b but not '.'

Is that what you are looking for?

```
[^\.\b][+-]?[3-5]+[^\.\b]
```

Will match '43' but not '34.5'

Comment: [^\.\b] mean it can be ^\. OR \b. So this won't work. I tried that already lol.

Comment: What do you think `[\b]` means? A boundary is a zero-width assertion, so that can’t be used in a charclass.  Would you believe backspace?